# Export as csv or xsl file from SQL Server 2008 express R2

Tags: sql-server, export

I am basically LAMP developer got some assignment where SQL Server is required. I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and imported backup file in it.

Now, I want to export user table in excel or csv but not able to do that.

Can anyone tell me how can I export table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to look at using [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx).

If you want to export a small amount of data, you can also `SELECT` the data in [SQL Server Management Studio](http://learningsqlserver.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-basics/), and highlight / copy / paste it into Excel, or rt click save as.

Comment: Ah, I see. So there is no tool here that can export data into readable formate like excel or csv?

Comment: You can do results to file which creates an .rpt file. Seems like I've seen add-ons to spit it out as Excel in the past. You can check this also: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/  Or try the wizard: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx  Also can rt click on your SSMS results and do save to file. That might be easiest if it's a one time export

Comment: Cool, I was able to query and than save as csv. Thx friends.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a command-line tool to do something like this, then try BCP.  It's a bulk Import/Export command-line utility that comes with SQL Server.  It is somewhat limited in it's formatting options, but it can usually do the simpler forms of CSV, etc.